# In Swift, how to make a descendant of String? I get error "Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'String'" when trying to do that

Tags: swift, string, extension-methods

I want to have a function return a type which I can add a new function, but still can be generally recognized as `String` (still have all of `String`'s methods and still can be received by any parameter that received `String`).

But when I try to derive a class from `String`, I get this error:

> Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'String'

Of course, I can instead use an extension to extend the existing `String` to add that function, but I felt that this will pollute the `String` with unnecessary and unrelated functions for general use.

For example, functions that I want to add might be like this:

```
class ImageUrl : String {

    func getImage (callback: ((UIImage?)->Void)) { ... }

}
```

or like this:

```
class Base64 : String {

    var image : UIImage { ... }
    var data : Data { ... }
    var string : String { ... }

}
```

Which will be confusing if I extend these functions to the main String type.

How can I do this in Swift? Or is there any workaround to this? Thanks.

Comment: [String](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string) is implemented in Swift as `struct`. So there is no way of subclassing it.

Comment: `String` is a struct. Structs don't support inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot inherit from `String` in Swift, because it is a `struct`. You can only add functionality by using an `extension` as you mentioned, but this will not let you use stored properties (computed properties as you wrote in the question are allowed).

However, a better approach for your need would be to use composition:

```
class Base64 {

    let str: String

    required init(value: String) {
        self.str = value
    }
}
```

Here you can add your desired functionality.

Comment: Although `Base64` is probably a bad idea. `ImageUrl` from the question is probably a better example.

Comment: Yeah, this is my current approach. It's just sad that these classes cannot immediately conform to parameters that accept String. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `String` extension using the `fileprivate` modifier to avoid polluting the global namespace. The functions would then only be available to code in the source file rather than the global namespace.

```
fileprivate extension String {
  var image : UIImage { ... }
  var data : Data { ... }
  var string : String { ... }
}
```

Comment: “fileprivate” restricts access to the same source file, “internal” to the same module.

Comment: Ah. I though "module" and "source file" were the same thing. Good to know :).

Comment: This extension is meant to be used globally in the project, it's part of the current project. But I just want to make a little differentiation that if I see an ImageUrl type, it's still can conform to String, but you're able to have a little bit extra functions there. Not a big deal, but to know why String can't be derived is enough. Thanks.